Resize groups/elements within a SVG file in an automated way
I've created multiple digital art files that are currently stored in the .svg file format and scaled to the ISO A4 size. This are complext svg. i.e. multiple embedded groups.
I want to find a way to automate changing the width/length of specific layers in each file so that I can recreate versions of this files in different ratios e.g. 1:1, 3:2.
Is this possible and how can I automate this process? Fyi I don’t know javascript but I’m familiar with python script.
Diagram

I've tried using a couple of different svg editing libraries in python however none of them seem to achieve the result I am looking for.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Where will these be used?  SVG files do not usually have an absolute size.  They expand to fit the container they're displayed in.

Thank you for your response. The aim ultimately is to export these files as .pngs in several different ratio aspects.

What applications or modules are you using to convert/export the SVG?
